# using Qooxdoo components without using the whole framework?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

Is Qooxdoo only usable if you want to write your entire application with it?
I would only like to use the table component. Kind of like Extjs building its own  grid component after you register which table element you'd like it to transform.

Answer (score 2):

Qooxdoo can be used embeded in a normal webpage, BUT the development methodology is radically different from what you are used to in ordinary web ui toolkits. With qooxdoo it is all about programming javascript, without HTML or CSS in the mix ... so transforming a HTML table element into a qooxdoo table is not something for starters ... you may be better served using something simple for this task ...

This is not to discourage you from using qooxdoo, best is probably to work thorough the [hello world](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.1/helloworld) app to get a feel for things.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed qooxdoo in traditional Web pages. It's called an [inline application](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.1/ui_inline).